# Warning: Undefined property: wpdb::$actionscheduler_actions

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php

I'm updated my WordPress website on local with Wampserver MySQL Version:8.0.31, php - 8.0.26, MariaDB Version: 10.10.2 after that I'm getting error below
Warning: Undefined property: wpdb::$actionscheduler_actions in C:\wamp64\www\aa\wp-includes\class-wpdb.php on line 789

```
public function __get( $name ) {
        if ( 'col_info' === $name ) {
            $this->load_col_info();
        }

        return $this->$name;
    }
```

==========
'Also get this:
Warning: The magic method Vc_Manager::__wakeup() must have public visibility in C:\wamp64\www\aa\wp-content\plugins\js_composer\include\classes\core\class-vc-manager.php on line 202'

```
public function getRoleAccess() {
        if ( ! $this->role_access ) {
            require_once vc_path_dir( 'CORE_DIR', 'access/class-vc-role-access.php' );
            $this->role_access = new Vc_Role_Access();
        }

        return $this->role_access;
    }
```

===================
WordPress database error: [Table 'T.a' doesn't exist]
SELECT a.action_id FROM a WHERE 1=1 AND a.hook='woo_sc_import_coupons_from_csv' AND a.status IN ('pending') ORDER BY a.scheduled_date_gmt ASC LIMIT 0, 1

I'm trying to alter table
`ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE=MyISAM;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Comment: Please don't use unrelated tags - or explain how your problem is related to Composer. Also, did you check whether all plugins you are using are compatible with PHP 8.0? Keep in mind that this is an outdated version